# SQL Syntax error when trying to perform "replace into" from JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am using a Java application to access my MySQL Database and absolutely everything is working perfectly fine.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to run the following:

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmtSql = "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; \n replace into database.user (EMail,Nickname,WebPassword,registerdOn,ProfilePic,usertype) values ('" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pass+ "','" +joined+ "','" +profPic+ "','" +type + "');\n SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;";
stmt.executeQuery(stmtSql);
```

I have printed this as well and it gives me this which works perfectly fine if I just run it in MySQL directly

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
replace into animelicious.user (EMail,Nickname,WebPassword,registerdOn,ProfilePic,usertype) values ('somemail@hotmail.com','someperson','justapw','2017-11-01','url','0');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

I am aware of the foreign_key check setting being a dirty workaround but as far as I know it should work.

Some more useful information might be:
Yes the user already exists.
Only the EMail and Nickname are unique and only Nickname is a foreign key.
Only EMail is replaced the rest of the column stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.addBatch("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;");
stmt.addBatch"replace into database.user (EMail,Nickname,WebPassword,registerdOn,ProfilePic,usertype) values ('" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pass+ "','" +joined+ "','" +profPic+ "','" +type + "');");
stmt.addBatch("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;");
stmt.executeBatch();
```